# How would I use SELECT statements to transform this data from two columns into three columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, pivot-table

I inherited a horribly-designed table where data is stored like this:

```
Period |  Identifier |   Value
----------------------------------
1      | AB1         | some number
1      | AB2         | some number
1      | AB3         | some number
1      | AB4         | some number
1      | AB5         | some number
1      | A1          | some number
1      | A2          | some number
1      | A3          | some number
1      | A4          | some number
1      | A5          | some number
2      | AB1         | some number
2      | AB2         | some number
2      | AB3         | some number
2      | AB4         | some number
2      | AB5         | some number
2      | A1          | some number
2      | A2          | some number
2      | A3          | some number
2      | A4          | some number
2      | A5          | some number
```

I'm trying to use SELECT statements that will get data into this format:

```
Row # | First value | Second value
1     | A1's number | AB1's number     // The next 5 rows are data from period 1
2     | A2's number | AB2's number
3     | A3's number | AB3's number
4     | A4's number | AB4's number
5     | A5's number | AB5's number
6     | A1's number | AB1's number     // These 5 rows are from period 2
7     | A2's number | AB2's number
8     | A3's number | AB3's number
9     | A4's number | AB4's number
10    | A5's number | AB5's number
```

`AB%` and `A%` are two separate ID's of that format, which mildly frustrates `WHERE LIKE ...` clauses, I think. I'm not entirely sure the data can be forced into the desired format, but my supervisor asked me to look into it.

My initial attempt, for which I don't know the SQL code for, would be to look at the row number itself and work with, but as I said, I'm unsure how to progress down that route.

Right now, the data is in SQL Server, but it will be accessed from SAS using `proc sql`. I think those standards conform to SQL Server for the most part, even though `DECLARE` isn't supported.

And no, I don't know whose idea it was to store the data in this fashion...

Comment: is the max length of the digit portion 1 or greater?

Comment: @JTC Are you referring to the identifier? The max length can be 2, I believe (up to A99 or AB99).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using SAS, then I'd just use PROC TRANSPOSE.  Get the data to include a label variable, which determines which variable the data will be moved to:

```
data datatable;
infile datalines dlm='|';
input
Period Identifier $ Value $;
datalines;
1      | AB1         | some number
1      | AB2         | some number
1      | AB3         | some number
1      | AB4         | some number
1      | AB5         | some number
1      | A1          | some number
1      | A2          | some number
1      | A3          | some number
1      | A4          | some number
1      | A5          | some number
2      | AB1         | some number
2      | AB2         | some number
2      | AB3         | some number
2      | AB4         | some number
2      | AB5         | some number
2      | A1          | some number
2      | A2          | some number
2      | A3          | some number
2      | A4          | some number
2      | A5          | some number
;;;
run;

data have;
set datatable;
idlabel = compress(identifier, ,'d');
byval = compress(identifier,,'kd');
run;

proc sort data=have;
by period byval;
run;
proc transpose data=have out=want;
by period byval;
id idlabel;
var value;
run;
```

If for some reason you HAVE to do it in SQL, you are best off doing it as a join to itself.  You want to join the row where period=1 and compress(identifier,,'kd')=1 for both AB and A, so you can do that:

```
proc sql;
  create table want as 
    select A.period, AB.value as AB, A.value as A
    from (select * from have where compress(identifier,,'d')='AB') AB, 
         (select * from have where compress(identifier,,'d')='A') A
    where AB.period=A.period
    and compress(AB.identifier,,'kd') = compress(A.identifier,,'kd');
quit;
```

But the PROC TRANSPOSE option is likely to be more efficient than the self join, I'd think (and more flexible, if your data isn't quite as pretty as you show).

Answer (score 2):

If the "B" in the identifier is *only* used to differentiate between type A and type AB identifiers then you can simply remove that letter and join on the result:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY AData.Period, AData.[Identifier]) AS [Row #]
    , AData.[Identifier] AS [First Value]
    , ABData.[Identifier] AS [Second Value]
FROM YourTable AData
-- Change to a LEFT JOIN if not all A's have AB's.
JOIN YourTable ABData
    -- NOTE: Assumes that 'B' is the only differentiator between
    -- AData and ABData's Identifier column and that it is
    -- not repeated as part of the common identifier.
    ON AData.[Identifier] = REPLACE(ABData.[Identifier], 'B', '')
```

You are absolutely correct - it is not a terribly great schema - this will probably need a full table scan.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring the trickiness of relating A to AB across their specific periods for a second, if the data were able to be related somehow, I would select the format you are looking for by doing an inner join on the table to itself, thus:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY a.Period, a.Identifier, b.Identifier), 
       a.Value, 
       b.Value 
FROM TableName a 
  INNER JOIN TableName b ON join_mechanism 
ORDER BY a.Period, a.Identifier, b.Identifier
```

Now, to fill in the join mechanism, the obvious part would be to have a.Period = b.Period.  The questionable part is an idea that you might try a string replace if this text is static.  So REPLACE(a.Identifier, 'A', 'AB') = b.Identifier.

Thus, all told, you would have:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY a.Period, a.Identifier, b.Identifier), 
       a.Value, 
       b.Value 
FROM TableName a 
  INNER JOIN TableName b ON a.Period = b.Period AND REPLACE(a.Identifier, 'A', 'AB') = b.Identifier 
ORDER BY a.Period, a.Identifier, b.Identifier
```

Note: The SELECT statements have not been tested, I'm assuming you are using are relatively new version of MSSQL that supports row_number.